# DAX, Power BI: Measure or column that flags users with multiple rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table like this:

| Name | Task | Active Task | Active User | Assigned Date | Completed date | CompletionPercentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | no1 | TRUE | TRUE | 11/09/2022 | 10/10/2022 | 100 |
| A | no3 | FALSE | TRUE | 01/02/2020 | 02/04/2020 | 100 |
| A | no2 | TRUE | TRUE | 05/10/2022 | 05/11/2022 | 100 |
| B | no1 | TRUE | TRUE | 05/02/2022 | 06/10/2022 | 100 |
| B | no2 | TRUE | TRUE | 04/07/2022 |  | 54.32098765 |
| C | no2 | TRUE | TRUE | 10/12/2021 | 10/01/2022 | 100 |
| C | no1 | TRUE | TRUE | 04/07/2022 | 04/08/2022 | 100 |
| D | no2 | TRUE | TRUE | 02/15/2022 | 04/10/2022 | 100 |
| D |  | TRUE | TRUE | 04/03/2022 |  | 92.30769231 |
| F | no1 | TRUE | TRUE | 05/10/2022 |  | 1.666666667 |
| G | no2 | TRUE | TRUE |  |  | 53.08641975 |
| H | no1 | TRUE | TRUE |  | 10/05/2022 | 100 |
| I | no4 | TRUE | TRUE |  |  |  |
| J | no4 | TRUE | FALSE |  | 11/05/2021 | 100 |
| K | no3 | FALSE | TRUE |  |  |  |

I am trying to calculate if there are users who have more than 1 task assigned and more than 1 task completion:

```
Users with more than 1 task =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Task] ),
        DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Name] ),
        'Table'[Active Task] = TRUE (),
        'Table'[Active User] = TRUE (),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Table'[Assigned Date], 'Calendar'[Date] )
    ) > 1,
    1
)
```

```
Users with more than 1 completion =
IF (
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Task] ),
        DISTINCT ( 'Table'[Name] ),
        'Table'[Active Task] = TRUE (),
        'Table'[Active User] = TRUE (),
        'Table'[CompletionPercentage] = 100,
        USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Table'[Completed date], 'Calendar'[Date] )
    ) > 1,
    1
)
```

With these measures however I am not able to get aggregates if I need to view, for example, by fiscal year:

[image]

Is there any way to get the sums of users who have multiple tasks and completions by year?
Thanks a lot for any help!

Later edit:

I used @Ozan-Sen 's formula and it works when viewing the data by Name or Country, but not when using Calendar Year or FY dimensions:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LG3VU.png)

```
#new Users with more than 1 task = VAR Tbl = ADDCOLUMNS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[Name] ), "Total_Task", CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Task] ), 'Table'[Active Task] = TRUE (), 'Table'[Active User] = TRUE () ) ) RETURN COUNTX ( FILTER ( Tbl, [Total_Task] > 1 ), [Name] )
```

```
#new Users with more than 1 completion = VAR Tbl = ADDCOLUMNS ( SUMMARIZE ( 'Table', 'Table'[Name] ), "Total_Task", CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Task] ), 'Table'[Active Task] = TRUE (), 'Table'[Active User] = TRUE (), 'Table'[CompletionPercentage] = 100, USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Table'[Completed date], 'Calendar'[Date] ) ) ) RETURN CALCULATE(COUNTX ( FILTER ( Tbl, [Total_Task] > 1 ), [Name] ), USERELATIONSHIP ( 'Table'[Completed date], 'Calendar'[Date] ))
```

In the pbix sample data here https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20221202bvPUEAuG, there are 3 users with multiple tasks in FY22 and 1 in FY23, but only the 3 ones in FY22 are displayed in the visual when adding FY. Likewise, there are 2 users with multiple tasks completed (1 in FY22 and 1 in FY23), but none are displayed with Calendar dimensions. I would like to have an accurate aggregate view by Calendar FY, can anyone help or explain what is the issue is?

Comment: Thank you for your example dataset, would you mind also providing your desired output? I see your picture, but it does not show what you believe the numbers should be.

Comment: Thanks for asking. I would like to be able to view aggregates of "Users with more than 1 completion" and "Users with more than 1 task" by dimensions such as Calendar or Country. Pbix sample dataset here: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20221202Hj9kMwe1 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try this solution:

I guess you have such a model:

[image: Model View]

Then Let's define measures:

```
Users with more than 1 task =
VAR Tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[Name] ),
        "Total_Task",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( YourTable[Task] ),
                'YourTable'[Active Task] = TRUE (),
                'YourTable'[Active User] = TRUE ()
            )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTX ( FILTER ( Tbl, [Total_Task] > 1 ), [Name] )



Users with more than 1 completion =
VAR Tbl =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE ( YourTable, YourTable[Name] ),
        "Total_Task",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( YourTable[Task] ),
                'YourTable'[Active Task] = TRUE (),
                'YourTable'[Active User] = TRUE (),
                'YourTable'[CompletionPercentage] = 100,
                USERELATIONSHIP ( YourTable[Completed date], 'Calendar'[Date] )
            )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTX ( FILTER ( Tbl, [Total_Task] > 1 ), [Name] )
```

If we test it on a visual:

[image: Result]

Update Requested from @Cristina:

```
#new Users with more than 1 task_BY_Calendar = 
VAR IterateByFY = ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE ( 'Table','Calendar'[FY]),
        "Total_Task",
            CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[Task] ),
                'Table'[Active Task] = TRUE (),
                'Table'[Active User] = TRUE ()
            )
    )
    RETURN
    SUMX(IterateByFY,[Total_Task])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, @Ozan!

I used your formula and it provides the correct aggregates when viewing the data by a dimension like Country, but I don't understand why it does not work when adding a Calendar dimension. I have uploaded the sample pbix dataset here if you want to take a look. https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20221202Hj9kMwe1 Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for editing my post, @Peter, I was not able to format to table when I posted.

Comment: @Cristina Please Check my update at the bottom of my post. I updated it! You need to integrate Related columns on the calendar table into your iteration.

Comment: Hi, @Ozan, thanks again for your input. I tried adding the Calendar dimension into the summarization, but now only 3 users are displayed instead of 4 in #new Users with more than 1 task_BY_Calendar. When doing the same thing in #new Users with more than 1 completion By year, there are no results (no aggregates and also no totals). Thanks! https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20221202Wn3ojZln

Comment: Yes, @Cristina I noticed it! you're right! I am checking now!

Comment: @Cristina In 2023 Only one task available! Condition [Total_Task] > 1 fails! It means No users counted in 2023! All 2022 with a value of 3! Not Total 4!

Comment: Hi, @Ozan, you are right! Thanks for clearing this up, the issue is solved! Best regards!